# How can discard "peaks" values from a chart?

Tags: excel

I have this chart

[image]

where you can see that some points are far away from the "trend" of the curve. The chart represents $5,000$ values where each value corresponds to a specific hour of a day, month and year. In this case, it goes from  `01/01/18` until `05/08/18` (non-american format) and as you can see at the first lower peak, it was caused because at `12.00` the cost was $20$ USD but at `1.00 AM` it went up to $51$ USD.

I've read that some people just delete those 'peaks' values but I don't know if there's a better solution. This graph shows almost a year but I have in mind on graphing $10$ years of this prices so the situation could be worse. Do you know a better strategy? I'm thinking maybe in calculating average costs for every $6$ hours but it feels like a cheap solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you have two options to choose from:

- Aggregate your data
- Use a low-pass-filter

---

## Aggregating

Aggregating your data over long time periods is not cheap (whatever that means). It is a common way of displaying trends over long periods of time.

Take a look at how [Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/EURUSD:CUR) displays the exchange rate of EUR over USD.

You can filter by time period, and if you select 1 day, you see the hourly rate:

[image]

or you can filter by month, and see the rate aggregated by day. For them, **the last rate** is the important one, so that is the value you see. For you, however, will depend on your use case. You can choose to pick one of the following: **mean, median, mode, max, min, first, last** or anything else that makes sense for you.

[image]

---

## Signal processing filtering

If you want to take a more mathematical approach to your problem, you could use a **signal filtering technique to reduce high-frequencies** from your signal.

What you need is a [low-pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter).

If you are using Excel, you certainly [can do this](https://www.dsprelated.com/showthread/comp.dsp/25154-1.php).
However, I would recommend you do that in some programing language like Matlab or Python, that contain easier to use [signal processing packages](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html).